# acceso a un objeto/array/matriz en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, matriz

```
var currentToken = [{type: "_palabra_reservada", value: "let"}, {type: "identificador_", value: "c"}, {type: "operador_", value: "="}, {type: "constante_", value: "6"}, {type: "operador_", value: "*"}, {type: "constante_", value: "9"}]
```

si quiero acceder al `value:"let"`
colocaría esto `currentToken.type[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder a un valor de un objeto dentro de un array seria algo así:

```
currenToken[0]
```

para acceder a la primera posición del array que devolvería un objeto

luego que estamos posicionados en la primera posicion nos moveriamos como si fuera un objeto normal

```
obj.value
```

esto devolvería el valor de la propiedad value del objeto

y todo junto seria:

```
currenToken[0].value
```

esto devolveria "let"

Comment: muchas gracias!